# express throws error as `body-parser deprecated undefined extended`

Tags: node.js, express

In my node app, I am using express. all works fine, But i am getting error in the `cmd`. I use all are updated modules...

**my code :**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jade = require('jade');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


app.use(bodyParser.json()); // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded()); // to support URL-encoded bodies


app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.render('index.jade');
});

app.get('/login',function(req,res){
    res.render('index.jade');
});

app.post('/login',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
});

app.get('/signup',function(req,res){
    res.render('signup.jade');
});

var env = process.env.PORT || 3000;


app.listen(env, function(req, res){
    console.log('i am working!');
});
```

**Error:**

```
D:\myLogin>node app
body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option app.js:11:20 //why i am getting this?
i am working!
{ username: 'jbarif@gmail.com', password: 'pass' } // i am getting response
```

Can any help me to understand this issue please?

Comment: @RamprasathSelvam - Yes, It was!!

Comment: @RamprasathSelvam - may something wrong with your code, version of module or integration, please check

Comment: Where do we vote for the worst error message ever? Especially considering this is highly likely to happen, the message just looks like a bag of random words.

Answer (score 429, accepted):

You have to explicitly set `extended` for `bodyParser.urlencoded()` since [the default value is going to change in the next major version](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/3f1b02247702c2966d33ee73610a98d54cf32fe8/lib/types/urlencoded.js#L41-L44) of `body-parser`. Example:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Since `express` 4.16.0, you can also do:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

Comment: @SamarthAgarwal According to the [readme](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/tree/3f1b02247702c2966d33ee73610a98d54cf32fe8#bodyparserurlencodedoptions), it uses the `qs` module to parse the body which allows for a nested array like syntax to be parsed such as `test[foo][bar]=baz` (which becomes `{'test': {'foo': {'bar': 'baz'}}}`)

Comment: @BaileyParker is your comment related to the `extended:true` expression? I think that the expression is nested.

Comment: For its meaning, see: \
node.js - What is the meaning of "bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))" and "bodyParser.json()" in Express.js? - Stack Overflow \
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55558402/what-is-the-meaning-of-bodyparser-urlencoded-extended-true-and-bodypar

Answer (score 81):

**Attention:** With `express version => 4.16.0` the `body-parser` middleware was added back under the methods [**`express.urlencoded()`**](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.urlencoded) and [**`express.json()`**](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json)

**Which can be used as:**

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})); 
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: so, no need of `npm i body-parser` ?

Comment: That is correct, do not install body-parser, it's already included

Answer (score 20):

The error says you need to provide the extended option for the body-parser like so:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

Answer (score 12):

## Don't use body-parser

It's now built-in with new versions of Express, you can access request body just like this only using **express**:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.json()) // To parse the incoming requests with JSON payloads
```

Hence, you can now uninstall body-parser using `npm uninstall body-parser`

**To get the POST content, you can use `req.body`**

```
app.post("/yourpath", (req, res)=>{

    var postData = req.body;

    //Or if this doesn't work

    var postData = JSON.parse(req.body);
});
```

Answer (score 7):

As from **Express** version 4.16.0, you're expected to pass in **extended** property inside the **bodyParser.urlencoded()**

```
//  parse JSON-encoded bodies and URL-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

See npm.js documentation page for sample: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser#expressconnect-top-level-generic

If you're using **Node v16.xx.x** and **"express": "^4.17.x"** and above, there is no need again to use bodyPerser. It is now incorporated with **express** by default.
Simply do the following below:

```
//  parse JSON-encoded bodies and URL-encoded bodies
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Comment: bodyParser is depriciated still getting this warning

Comment: This helped me, I was confused because after removing body-parser from my app I was still seeing this error.

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin you don't need Body-Parser anymore inasmuch as you're using a version of  Node v16.xx.x and Express: ^4.17.x

Answer (score 7):

If you facing `'bodyParser' is deprecated.`

**Just do**

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})); 
app.use(express.json());
```

Note: If you are using `4.16.0` or later express version.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **Node v16.xx.x** and **"express": "^4.17.x"**, there is no need again to use bodyParser. It is now incoporated with Express by default.
Simply do the following below:

```js
// parse JSON-encoded bodies and URL-encoded bodies
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using node version v13.12.0:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
```

Comment: Today's date has no bearing on what version of Node someone is using.

Comment: This is the only approach that works. Sadly, I saw it in very few blog posts, forums, etc., and the amount of confusion regarding this is through the roof!

Answer (score 1):

You don`t need "body-parser" explicitly installed now. This will work

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are here after christmas from 2020 you just have to put the midlawares in order before your express declaretion and after the routes declaration[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aokA8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `body-parser` anymore.

In the new version of express.js, this option of parsing is available.

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Answer (score -2):

> Set limit 50 MB for avoid data handling error., In urlencode limit
>   50mb is for help you to pass imageData throw url

```
  app.use(bodyParser.json({
        limit : '50mb'    ///////// LIMIT for JSON
      }));

    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        limit : '50mb', ///////// LIMIT for URL ENCODE (image data)
        extended : true
      }));
```