# mongoose is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/olatundegaruba/nodejs-restful-apis-in-10-minutes-q0sgsfhbd), which creates a To-do list using express and mongo. I am getting the following errors:

```
body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option server.js:12:20
C:\todoListApi\api\controllers\todoListController.js:4
var Task = mongoose.model('Tasks');
           ^
ReferenceError: mongoose is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\todoListApi\api\controllers\todoListController.js:4:12)
    ...
```

The `body-parser deprecated` error I have tried to fix using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25471856/express-throws-error-as-body-parser-deprecated-undefined-extended) to no avail (although it seems like more of a warning).

The mongoose error doesn't make any sense because mongoose ids defined directly before it:

```
var mongooose = require('mongoose').Mongoose,
    Task = mongoose.model('Tasks');
```

But it's also defined in server.js:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Task = require('./api/models/todoListModel'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/Tododb');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded(bodyParser.json()));

var routes = require('./api/routes/todoListRoutes');
routes(app);

app.listen(port);

console.log('todo list RESTful API server started on: ' + port)
```

I changed this from the original tutorial to add `.Mongoose` because this post said it would work.

Comment: you required mongoose in a variable `mongooose` with 3 'o'

Comment: @Jérôme: Nice spot :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by [Jérôme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1856207/j%c3%a9r%c3%b4me) in his comment, your mongoose variable is being defined as `mongooose` but then being accessed throughout your code as `mongoose` without the 3rd `o`.

As for the body parser issue, you don't wrap `bodyParser.json()` within the `bodyParser.urlencoded()` middleware. `bodyParser.json()` is returning its own middleware function that needs to be passed directly to the express server.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: OK, that worked, but now it's giving me `Task = mongoose.model is not a function` any ideas?

Comment: OK, I took out `.Mongoose` and that fixed it. Thanks!