# TypeError: bodyParser.urlecoded is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I use nodejs and express for my back-end web development.

I want the app to use bodyParser
**app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));**

But I am getting this error on my server:

**TypeError: bodyParser.urlecoded is not a function**

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: have you imported/required the bodyParser module?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of "bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))" and "bodyParser.json()" in Express.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55558402/what-is-the-meaning-of-bodyparser-urlencoded-extended-true-and-bodypar)

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead

```
const express=require('express');
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
```

express.urlencoded() middleware has been added to provide request body parsing

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the issue :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json({ extended: true }));
```