# How can I remove dependency on body-parser?

Tags: node.js, express, npm, backend

I already installed express module and body-parser now I can use express to get all the things I required from the user and there's no need of body-parser anymore, so how do I remove it?
[when i start my server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEEyP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove it with `npm uninstall body-parser` when you are in the folder where package.json file lives.

Answer (score 1):

If your express version is greater than 4.16.0, then you do not need body parser at all as mentioned here -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49704644/7895283